# How to rig some Control.OnMouseEnter event with separate Label.Caption update

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have 12 shapes

```
Shape1
Shape2
.....
Shape12
```

and I have 12 labels

```
Label13
Label14
......
Label24
```

I was wondering if there is a way to write such a function, that on mouse enter on a shape would assign corresponding label to a different label, for example Label25:

```
Label25 :=  
OnMouseEnter
shape1 -> label13
shape2 -> label14
...
shape12 -> label24
```

So if the mouse entered Shape1, Label25 would become equal to Label13, and if mouse entered Shape2, Label25 would become equal to Label14 and continue till if mouse entered Shape12 Label25 would become equal to Label24.

I know I can write

```
label25 := labelxx
```

on each of the mouse enter events. But thought there could be an easier way as the name of the label and shape correspond, where label # is 12 more then the shape # everytime.

After adding the suggested,  I added this

```
procedure TFZone1Mod7.ChangeText(sender: TObject);
var
  ShapeOrderNo: integer;
  FoundComponent: TComponent;
begin
  if TryStrToInt(copy(TShape(Sender).Name,6,MaxInt),ShapeOrderNo) then
    begin
      FoundComponent := FindComponent('label'+inttostr(ShapeOrderNo+12));
      if (FoundComponent is TLabel) then
            Label25.Caption := TLabel(FoundComponent).Caption
      else
          showmessage('not found');
    end;
  showmessage('failed try');

end;

procedure TFZone1Mod7.Shape1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
    changetext(self);
end;

end.
```

but everytime its ran i get failed try. 
Am i sending the info wrong?

Comment: i was going to try and use TLamam's code

Comment: If the shape + label are associated and share the same container, Use a frame (e.g. `TShapeFrame`) to hold a shape + label (+ something more  in the future). write your event handlers/tasks/logic for that frame. then create 12 `TShapeFrame`s (in run/design time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't like this kind of a design, but well, you can use the common event handler for all your shapes and use the [`FindComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) function to find a component by name there. You might then write comething like this (please note that it's untested, written just in browser):

```
var
  ShapeOrderNo: Integer;
  FoundComponent: TComponent;
begin
  // first try to convert a text behind "Shape", what should be a shape's order 
  // and if it's convertable to integer, then...
  if TryStrToInt(Copy(TShape(Sender).Name, 6, MaxInt), ShapeOrderNo) then
  begin
    // try to find a component with the name "label" + found shape order number
    // incremented by 12
    FoundComponent := FindComponent('label' + IntToStr(ShapeOrderNo + 12));
    // if the component is found, or to be more specific, if it's TLabel, then...
    if (FoundComponent is TLabel) then
      TLabel(FoundComponent).Caption := 'Hello from ' + TShape(Sender).Name;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: i like this, but how would i add it?  I have a forum with 12 shapes on it. Can i add this to say forum's OnMouseClick? I dont think that woudl work.. looks like i would still have to call this procedure from a OnShapeMouseEnter form.. Also i have about 30 forums all with same name, But i assume findcomponent would only look for components on that forum?

Comment: @Glen: Maybe it's time for a little refactoring.

Comment: @TLama: Could you please expand your answer with a kind of design that you would use? Just an idea for others who might stumble upon it

Comment: well i would love to .. kind of but i can never find a good forum for help. This is good for questions, but talk on how to go about this project..well there are no more delphi forums alive.. :(  thus I would just end up back where i am at now.

Comment: Ok, seems you don't like chat. Never mind, I just wanted to ask you, if every label is placed on that shape (for considering container component) or optionally suggest you to make a component from Ravaut123's idea. All the ways trying to connect components at runtime are in my view bad...

Comment: At work no skype , pm or even chat rooms here will work.. I know what i am doing can be done super simple, as i am doing 90% of repeat work

Comment: yea but websence blocks it due to the word chat.. lol At a later time i may see if i can get you on chat.. when iam home.

Comment: @Glen "Also i have about 30 forums all with same name, But i assume findcomponent would only look for components on that forum". - Can you explain that a bit further by editing the question?

Answer (score 2):

Add a property on your TShape.

```
 TMyShape= class(TShape)
 private
   FLinkLabel: TLabel;
 procedure SetLinkLabel(const Value: TLabel);
 published
   property LinkLabel: TLabel read FLinkLabel write SetLinkLabel;
 end;

 procedure TMyShape.SetLinkLabel(const Value: TLabel);
 begin
   FLinkLabel := Value;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 var
   oMyShape: TMyShape;
 begin
   oMyShape:= TMyShape.Create(self);
   oMyShape.Parent:= Self;
   oMyShape.LinkLabel:= self.Label1;
   oMyShape.OnMouseEnter:= OnShapeMouseEnter;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.OnShapeMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   if (sender is TMyShape) and
      ( TMyShape(Sender).LinkLabel <>Nil) then
   begin
     TMyShape(Sender).LinkLabel.Caption:= 'Hello';
   end;
 end;
```

I just set a tlabel on the form and link the label with TMyShape.

Comment: @Glen: It just a demo. Make a package and register the Component and install. So you can drop the component on desgin time.

Comment: Registering a new package just for this little job seems an overkill. Especially when working in multi-programmers environment.

Comment: I really would had done that if thought about it, but i all ready have 20 + forums with shapes, and re-shapeing them and location would not be worth it.

Comment: @Krom: I hope you inherit all your components for the evironment. I do this for all my projects. If i want to change one of my components, I must not search in all my forms to change something on the component. If I want to use a TShape in My Project I inherted this with TXXShape and use only the TXXShape.

Comment: @Ravaut: +1, your approach has its niche.

Comment: @Glen: re-shapeing... Just search and replace the tShape into TXXShape in the dfm File and recompile.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not do controls management in Forms Designer and create them in runtime I would do it like so:

Declare an array of labels and array of shapes:

```
const
  ShapesCount = 20;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    fLabels: array [0..ShapesCount-1] of TLabel;
    fShapes: array [0..ShapesCount-1] of TShape;
```

In runtime assign to each shape a `Tag` with its index.

```
procedure TForm1.OnFormCreate;
begin
  for I := 0 to ShapesCount - 1 do  
  begin
    fShapes[I] := TShape.Create(..);
    fLabels[I] := TLabel.Create(..);
    fShapes[I].Tag := I;
    fShapes[I].OnMouseEnter := OnShapeMouseEnter;
  end;
end;
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
procedure TForm1.OnShapeMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Assert(Sender is TShape);
  Label25.Caption := fLabels[TShape(Sender).Tag].Caption;
end;
```

---

EDIT: Looking a little further, you probably have an array with Lable.Captions already, so you could take Label25.Caption right from there.

Comment: if i did this, i would still have to add     Label25.caption := flabels[tshape(sender).tag].caption;  to each onmouseenter()  ?

Comment: No, you assign the same handler to each shapes OnMouseEnter event. The handler checks what Tag the Sender shape has and takes appropriate label caption. Thats the point of it ;)

Comment: i do think it would work, but i dont create at run time. I should of added that to question. but will still give credit.

Comment: Then you would need an array that says which Shape is associated with which Label and adapt it to TLama answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to re-write the creation of the labels then use findcomponent:

same handler for all shapes

```
procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
var
  ActiveShape: TShape;
  StrName: string;
  ActiveLabel: TComponent;
begin
  if Sender is TShape then
  begin
    ActiveShape := TShape(Sender);
// Only works if Shapes are named Shape1..12 and the labels Label1..12 !!
    StrName := 'Label' + copy(ActiveShape.name, 6, length(ActiveShape.name)); 
    ActiveLabel := FindComponent(StrName);
    if ActiveLabel is TLabel then
      Label25.Caption := TLabel(ActiveLabel).Caption;
  end;
end;
```

This will do what you need if a bit messily :)

[EDIT]
It occurred to me that there is a simply way to improve this and satisfy your the need for a label with a different "name_number":

In the designer set the Tag property of each TShape to be the label number you want associated with it. So set shape one's Tag to be 13 (to stay with the question) then

```
procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
var
  ActiveShape: TShape;
  StrName: string;
  ActiveLabel: TComponent;
begin
  if Sender is TShape then
  begin
    ActiveShape := TShape(Sender);
    StrName := 'Label' + IntToStr(ActiveShape.Tag); // find tag numbered label
    ActiveLabel := FindComponent(StrName);
    if ActiveLabel is TLabel then
      Label25.Caption := TLabel(ActiveLabel).Caption;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: To your note *this only works for labels 0-9!!*, why do you think ? You are `Copy`ing the order number in length of the shape name, what might be assuming just a `Shape` portion of the name range up to `99999`.

Comment: @TLama [Blush] I added the note afterwards - That is what I really meant.. If shapes and labels are not named Shape1..Shape12 and the labels Label1..12 then this will not work. Editing again. Your edit yes - it should be "is Tlabel" not <> nil.